# Mobile / Tablet IOS forces double tap on certain links and elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Client is saying that certain links require 2 taps on mobile and Ipad (ios). The weirdest part about this is that on my personal website I use hover effects and many similar code blocks, and the hover animation triggers AND the link triggers when I tap on mobile.

I've done many google searches, even read many articles on this website tackling this issue, but can't seem to find a fix for my specific instance of it. It appears to have to do with hover states. Is there no workaround? Generally what I am seeing is on a button, a link, or image that I have assigned a "hover" effect to, whether it be color change or opacity, when I tap on IOS the hover state triggers before the link. I don't remember this being an issue in the past. Maybe there is something I can do to keep the hover states, because sometimes (especially on the "stories" page) the hover state is the only thing indicating that you can interact with an object.

PASSWORD for the links below : viewthisthing

https://pfp-dev.myshopify.com/pages/physical-therapists - Bottom button

https://pfp-dev.myshopify.com/pages/contact - "contact us any time at.." the mailto link requires double tap

https://pfp-dev.myshopify.com/pages/stories - The bottom portrait grid has a opacity hover effect on desktop - mobile requires 2 taps
AND MORE.

My website where you can see that the links work while simultaneously triggering the hover states:
[www.lancewalkerdesigns.com](http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com) - the portfolio grid section is a great example. On desktop its a hover state to show the link, on mobile its shown by default. The link works perfectly.

Super confused as to why it works on mine and doesn't work on my clients.

Comment: There is another problem I noticed. When we open menu, 'Up-arrow' button shows above the menu. Your menu-opening/closing effects are awesome.

Comment: Thanks! could you possibly upload a screen shot? I am unable to recreate this issue

Comment: Check this: [Firefox - latest version](https://ibb.co/hgZMvDq) and [UC Web (based on Google Chrome) - latest version](https://ibb.co/N1631NQ)